# Fix for google-code-prettify w/ c#

Tags: c#, javascript

[Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) gives types and methods the same class when tokenizing c# so they are colored the same. This is because methods are pascal case in c# instead of camel case like in java. This affects my blog and **all stackoverflow c# code** since they use prettify too.

**Does anyone have a fix for this?**

If not, you can at least [star/vote the official bug](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/issues/detail?id=70) that was reported in Mar/2009 so the authors take another look.

Comment: Wow, the whoever "tawani" is on that issue sure knows how to sweet talk people.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I actually wrote my own syntax highlighting library to solve problems like this. It's pretty similar to prettify but you have to specify the language explicitly.

- [Website](http://sunlightjs.com/)
- [Demo](http://sunlightjs.com/demo.html)

Comment: +1 for better C# syntax highlighting in your lib (Sunlight v1.17.437 vs. Syntax Highlighter v3.0.83)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible for identical syntax to have different meanings. There just isn't enough information to properly syntax highlight everything.

Take a look at this example:

```
static class Program
{
    class Foo { public class Bar { public static void Func() { } } }
    class Foo2 { public static Baz Bar2 { get; set; } }
    class Baz { public void Func2() { } }

    static void Main()
    {
        Foo.Bar.Func();
        Foo2.Bar2.Func2();
    }
}
```

In the first line, Bar is an inner class, and should be highlighted green. In the second line, Bar2 is a property of type Foo2, and should be highlighted black. Both Func and Func2 are functions, and should be highlighted black.

Here's how Visual Studio highlights that code.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is that without context, it's impossible to find out whether it's a method or a type.**

Take the following example:

```
var value = new Test();

Test();
```

This example instantiates a new `Test` and then calls the method `Test`. The only way to find out which is a class and which is a type is by having 1. the entire code base and 2. a compiler.

And then I haven't even touched invalid code.

That being said, I think that the current prettifier as used by SO does a terrific job of highlighting the code samples without any context whatsoever.

Comment: well there's the 'new' keyword to identify that case no?

Comment: Yes, that is right, but you still have problems. What do you do when someone chooses not-pascal case?

Answer (score 2):

## [TextMate](http://macromates.com/) (OS X) or [E-TextEditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) (Windows)

#### TextMate/E-TextEditor will generate HTML & CSS from syntax highlighting for many, many languages.

Here is what you do:

1. Open the file in TextMate/E-TextEditor
2. Select the language from the menu at the bottom of the screen if it doesn't choose it automatically
3. Go to Bundles->TextMate->Create HTML From Document

   - This will create all the HTMl/CSS in a new document.
   - Note: Windows users also choose the 'TextMate' bundle (not 'E-TextEditor')
4. Profit!

*Note: You will have to install the C# bundle for C# syntax (every other common language is included).  To do this, install the "Get Bundles" bundle, and use that to install the C# bundle.*

EDIT: Reading the comments I realized TextMate is only a solution for Mac users.  Sometimes I forget about Windows.

#### You can also use [E-TextEditor](http://www.e-texteditor.com/) for Windows.  The steps are the same.

Comment: Recently I've been using the CopySourceAsHtml addin for Visual Studio http://copysourceashtml.codeplex.com/