# Google Prettify - C# Color Scheme

Tags: c#, syntax-highlighting, color-scheme, prettify

I'm using Google's Prettify.js library for highlighting syntax. Working great.

It auto-detects languages and applies a generic color scheme. But it seems C# is picked up as a generic C-variant and is colored very similar to Java.

I found an alternate color scheme that looks like the SonOfObsidian theme, which is neat but doesn't work for my purpose and app scheme.

**Question:**

Is there an open-source C# color scheme available for Prettify.js?

Comment: Java and C# are so similar syntactically, how would you want them colored differently?

Comment: You might find this question handy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1850639/fix-for-google-code-prettify-w-c-sharp

Comment: @DaveSwersky - you're right. they are. but the color scheme literally is more like a Java IDE. I could open up the scheme and tweak it to look different, but I'm trying not to do something I'm sure someone else has already done. I'm looking for the generic VS.Net C# syntax colors.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667097/how-to-get-google-prettify-to-render-more-like-visual-studio
this will resolve your issue..add a .cs and include it